# Apache Storm Watchdog - Supervisord blocking Ambari?i

Tags: hadoop, supervisord, apache-storm, hortonworks-data-platform

I am currently playing with Hortonworks new HDP 2.2 preview and seeing some weird behaviour with storm.
A number of tutorials suggest that you install supervisord as a watchdog process as storm is a fail fast application. When storm falls over you need something to restart it. I used easy_install to set it up supervisord as yum gives you the old 2.1 version. I currently have version 3 installed.

I bring up the sandbox, start the various storm bits and pieces and it works fine. I then install supervisord, set the supervisord.conf file to include the following at the bottom:

```
[program:storm-nimbus]
command=storm nimbus
directory=/usr/lib/storm
autorestart=true
user=storm

[program:storm-supervisor]
command=storm supervisor
directory=/usr/lib/storm
autorestart=true
user=storm

[program:storm-ui]
command=storm ui
directory=/usr/lib/storm
autorestart=true
user=storm
```

I then kick off the supervisor using: supervisord -c /etc/supervisord.conf
If I try to restart storm through ambari I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.1/services/STORM/package/scripts/drpc_server.py", line 58, in <module>
DrpcServer().execute()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 122, in execute
method(env)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 231, in restart
self.stop(env)
File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.1/services/STORM/package/scripts/drpc_server.py", line 50, in stop
service("drpc", action="stop")
File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/stacks/HDP/2.1/services/STORM/package/scripts/service.py", line 75, in service
Execute(format("kill {pid}"),
NameError: global name 'Execute' is not defined
```

Similar thing happens if I install the supervisor when storm is down. Its unable to restart. I am thinking that you can either have a watchdog (supervisor) or ambari looking after storm but not both? Is this correct? And if so why do the hortonworks tutorials tell you to install the supervisord?
If someone can help to explain this whole process I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: Is any of this *your code*?

Comment: It's standard Hortonworks released code. The question was from a configuration point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for coming to the party almost 3 years late, and I don't know how relevant the answer is to HDP 2.2.  However, on HDP 2.4 and later for sure, to get this working you have to tell Ambari that the Storm components are watchdogged by changing the start scripts.  For more info, see https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.1/bk_storm-component-guide/content/config-storm-supv.html